# How to use properties value as fixed value map at spring framework?

Tags: java, spring, object, properties

I have to mapping properties value as public static immutable Map.

I googling hard n have been try many solution to my code, but they always return null.

I try many way but nothing works for me..

Example Code

```
// properties

test.value=Hello


public interface TestObject {
  String getValue();
}

@Component
public class TestOne implements TestObject {
  
  @Value(${test.value})
  private String value;

  @Override
  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }
}

public class TestMap {
  // I wanna load TestObject at here as Map
  private static final Map<Integer, TestObject> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

  public TestObject getTestObject(int num) {
    return hashMap.get(num);
  }
}
```

My first try : Use static block

```
/// TestMap(HashMap) up here

static {
  hashMap.put(1, new TestOne());
  hashMap.put(2, new TestTwo()); // another class what implements TestObject
  ....
}
```

My first fail. I realized @Value annotation created at Runtime. so I try another way.

My second fail : singleton & instance block

```
/// TestMap(HashMap) up here

static TestMap testMap;

public static TestMap getInstance() {
        if (testMap == null) instance = new TestMap();
        return testMap;
}

{
  hashMap.put(1, new TestOne());
  hashMap.put(2, new TestTwo());
  ....
}
```

And It still return null and now I'm starting very confuse.

I thought instance block will be created after instance got initialize. so @Value will be excute at instance block. (therefore @Value annotation mapping properties value)

So I thought this code will be operate without any problem.

```
TestObject object = TestMap.getInstance().getTestObject(1);
System.out.println(object.getValue());
```

but it still return null.

Did I misunderstanding about instance and static?

or I using wrong way to mapping properties value as immutable?

I also try another way to load value at map(caching, another method ....) but it not that satisfied.

Comment: What is the spring specific part of your task? Are you already able to access the properties from the file in some way in your code? 
What will the map be used for?

Comment: As shown in the example, Map is used to find objects that implements the interface as number.

Comment: I think I still don't understand your problem fully. Could you please add a runnable example? (Either something with a main method or preferably a unit test). The code doesn't have to produce the correct result, neither does it need to use the spring annotations - simply put constant literals whereever you would annotate the @Value to load data from the properties file. I also don't get how exactly the relation of properties and the map keys (the numbers) is wanted. Is this something for you to learn working with Java and Spring? If it's a real world problem, maybe you explain your big picture

Comment: I wanna map constants value as Integer : Interface (for example -  1 : A what implements Alphabet interface, 2 : B, 3 : C ....) before runtime. when user input key value, application has to return matching value what implements Interface.

Comment: like this : TestObject obj = TestMap.get(input);

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `@Component` and `@Autowired` annotations. You can annotate your `Testone` class with `@Component` and inject it in the `Testone testone` object, rather than creating the new object of the `Testone` class.

```
@Component
public class TestOne implements TestObject {
  
  @Value(${test.value})
  private String value;

  @Override
  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }
}
```

And

```
@Autowired
TestOne testOne

hashMap.put(1, testOne);
```

Comment: I forgot to write @Component at example. anyway it still return null either when tried your way